# Socket.io Disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an application which basically uses `cookies` for session handling.

The aim is to display a message when a user `connects` and `disconnects`,

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // Logging when a new connection is, made!
    socket.emit('cookie_user_log');
    socket.on('cookie_value_log', function(x){
    console.log(x+ " Joined the conversation! :)");
    io.emit('welcome', x); // will display welcome HTML client-side message
  });
```

This works perfectly and I am able to view the message when a user `connects`.

But, a similar approach does not seem to work to handle disconnections.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    leave();
  });

function leave()
 {
  console.log("LEAVE IT");
  socket.emit('cookie_user_leave');
  socket.on('cookie_value_leave', function(x){
  console.log(x+ " Left the conversation! :)");
  io.emit('bye', x); // will display bye HTML client-side message
  });
 }
```

The output here is only:

```
LEAVE IT
```

And does not display the message! 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why would you be able to emit a message on a socket that has already been disconnected?

Comment: Well, I guess what I had in mind is a group-chat scenario and when one user disconnects, a message such as "[user1] disconnected" is broadcasted to the entire chat. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is output to other connected clients when another one disconnects then you could do something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // Logging when a new connection is, made!
  var user
  socket.emit('cookie_user_log');
  socket.on('cookie_value_log', function(x){
    user = x
    console.log(x+ " Joined the conversation! :)");
    io.emit('welcome', x); // will display welcome HTML client-side message
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    if (!user) return;
    console.log(user+ " Left the conversation! :)");
    io.emit('bye', user);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, @idbehold! Actually, what I am doing is: Displaying the message using io.emit() and also removing 'user' from an Array. Everything works perfectly now! I was almost going to give up on socket.io but will move forward now.